# How do I ignore missing trusted keys in apt sources.list?

Tags: apt, python, 8.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt)

i have a problem in ubuntu hardy:

i use an old hardy server that i may not upgrade with the historical sources:
   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com hardy

i want to install python2.6 from another source and tried this:
http://linuxverzion.blogspot.de/2010/12/install-python-26-on-ubuntu-804-lts.html

```
Add to /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/python-dev/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
deb-srchttp://ppa.launchpad.net/python-dev/ppa/ubuntu hardy main

#Import the pub key 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D81367B9
```

i changed it to my key but i get the error

```
gpg: Schlüssel D81367B9 von hkp Server keyserver.ubuntu.com anfordern
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: Keine gültigen OpenPGP-Daten gefunden.
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 0
```

is it possible to tell apt, that i dont care if the key exists?
i would like to **ignore the missing key**

(it is a messed up server anyway)

Comment: it seems like the length of the key is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ignored the error and installed python2.6 I just had to say Yes, install although I don't have the signed key