# “no public key available” on apt-get update

Tags: 14.04

When I do a `sudo apt-get update`, I encounter the following:

```
Fetched 189 B in 10s (18 B/s)                                                  
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1436387333
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What would be a good/recommended way to fix this?

Comment: The error `W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)` is there because chrome is not supported for 32 bit systems anymore. So, remove the ppa and chrome and use chromium instead because chrome will be outdated and dangerous (keep in mind you won't have flash since pepper flash is downloaded from google and can only work for 64bit systems nowadays).

Comment: I removed Google Chrome using `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable` and `rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf` and ran `sudo apt-get update` again. That message is still there.

Comment: You need to remove the ppa also from `Software & Updates`

Comment: I removed it from there. Now, the message reduces to: `W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org ./ Release: The following signatures` ... `were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1436387333`

Comment: Possibly some other ppa problem. Can you provide 2 links at your question using http://imgur.com/ , one with a screenshot of `Other Software` tab and a second with a screenshot of `Authentication` tab from `Software & Updates`?

Comment: @ThanosApostolou. [Other Software](http://i.imgur.com/Cdc6yYL.png), [Authentication](http://i.imgur.com/QhBXr8M.png)

Comment: The answer by Steven Myers is right. Did you follow correctly the instructions here https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:colomboem&package=dukto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the error was reduced based on the OP's previous response -- the following link should help: https://askubuntu.com/a/650051/382121 - Let us know if this resolves your issue Sandeep Chatterjee

Comment: I find two occurences of `opensuse` in my `sources.list` file.  `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./` and `# deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./` I am assuming the first occurence needs to be commented. However, it is not allowing me to save the file.

Comment: Just curious, have you sudo sources.list to open the file for editing? In this case it's possible the location the file sits in is not editable for normal permissions.

Comment: No, I opened the file using `Atom` editor. The location of `sources.list` is `/etc/apt`

Comment: `-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  3276 Jun 13 04:24 sources.list`. Do I need to change any permissions?

Comment: Ah ok. Sudo into the location using your terminal. I.E: sudo gedit location/of/sources.list - then make your changes and be sure to save the file. Let us know the results of this.

Comment: This is what I did. `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and then in `INSERT` mode commented the line `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./` and saved the file. Ran `sudo apt-get update` again without any errors. Answer accepted :)

Comment: Excellent news Sandeep! Glad your issue is resolved my friend. Let us know if we can do anything else for you :)

Comment: Don't just post a link as an answer. That isn't helpful if the link ever disappears. If the link is an askubuntu one then flag the question as a duplicate.