# Errors on apt-get update: Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I have been trying to figure out what is going on when I run apt-get update. I've tried going through the sources file and also using the Ubuntu Tweak to clean the sources list, but nothing is working.

When I run apt-get update I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable Release
```

Comment: I already went through this. It didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPG error:The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650032/gpg-errorthe-following-signatures-were-invalid-keyexpired) and [How to fix “W: Duplicate sources.list entry”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install (or update) the package called `Ubuntu Tweak` from the PPA called `tualatrix/ppa` which is described on this page: https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. However, this PPA does not contain any package that is compatible with your Ubuntu release (`xenial`) as it stopped being supported after `trusty`.

You could try to download the `deb` file for `trusty` and install that, but chances are the dependencies can not be fulfilled.

[This article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-tweak-is-now-officially-dead-and-buried-503672.shtml) explains in more detail what has happened, and advises you to install `Unity tweak` instead.

To clean this up, delete the lines containing `tualatrix` from your `sources.list` file and/or delete any files containing `tualatrix` from `sources.list.d`. Alternatively, install `ppa-purge` and do `sudo ppa-purge tualatrix/ppa`.

Finally, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again.