# How can I create a Ubuntu deb repository without gpg sign?

Tags: 16.04, deb, localrepository

I have a few Ubuntu `.deb` packages, and I want to install them on some PCs in my local network. I don't want to do gpg sign, just same as RedHat `createrepo`.

I have run

```
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

and shared the directory via HTTP. I created a `sources.list` file with

```
deb [arch=amd64] (link to http)  xenial non-free
```

After `apt update`

```
Err:14 repo.domain.com xenial Release.gpg                                   
  404  Not Found

: The repository 'https://repo.domain.com xenial Release' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried the solution from the question [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt) but without any success.

Ubuntu people help me please.