# How do I fix apt-add-repository "no such option: --allow-unauthenticated"?

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04, add-apt-repository

I'm running 18.04, and I'm attempting to install Wine, which has an unsigned repository. I tried bypassing this by using the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag, but I get an error

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository https:/dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ --allow-unauthenticated
Usage: apt-add-repository <sourceline>

apt-add-repository is a script for adding apt sources.list entries.
It can be used to add any repository and also provides a shorthand
syntax for adding a Launchpad PPA (Personal Package Archive)
repository.

<sourceline> - The apt repository source line to add. This is one of:
  a complete apt line in quotes,
  a repo url and areas in quotes (areas defaults to 'main')
  a PPA shortcut.
  a distro component

  Examples:
    apt-add-repository 'deb http://myserver/path/to/repo stable myrepo'
    apt-add-repository 'http://myserver/path/to/repo myrepo'
    apt-add-repository 'https://packages.medibuntu.org free non-free'
    apt-add-repository http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    apt-add-repository ppa:user/repository
    apt-add-repository ppa:user/distro/repository
    apt-add-repository multiverse

If --remove is given the tool will remove the given sourceline from your
sources.list

apt-add-repository: error: no such option: --allow-unauthenticated
```

I've seen other users on the site with the same version of Ubuntu claim this option works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check: apt-add-repository -help doesn't output an option for this parameter. apt-get has this it seems: https://askubuntu.com/a/74389/37213

Comment: There exist no `apt-add-repository --allow-unauthenticated` -> take a look at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html . However, `apt-get --allow-unauthenticated`exists. Please follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine for installation. For further posts please add links you are following the installation.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the option `--allow-unauthenticated` with the commands `apt` or `apt-get` but not with the command `add-apt-repository`.

Please take a look at https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu where it is very well explained how to add the desired repository.

> If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.

If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then run the following commands:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

Now you need to update the cache with

```
sudo apt update
```

And finally install with

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: Sorry to double dip, but how do I add the repository then?

Comment: Doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/tCrteLMb, I tried apt-update as well and got a similar result.

Comment: Please see my edit, now that I know which repository you want to add.